# PHP: string with decimals strips decimals when converting to float

Tags: php, string, floating-point, decimal

With the function floatval() I try to convert a string with decimals to a float, but it doesn´t give me the desired result. Here´s the code:

```
    $price_calc = str_replace(',','.',$price);
    $reduction_calc = str_replace(',','',$reduction);
    $reduction_calc = '1.'.$reduction;      

    $price_calc = floatval($price_calc);
    $reduction_calc = floatval($reduction_calc);

    $oldprice = $price_calc * $reduction_calc;
```

This chunk of code is from a scraper I´m building that fetches the price ($price) and the percentage of reduction($reduction). From that price and reduction I´m trying to calculate the old price.

Before being able to make the calculation I have to convert both $price and $reduction to float. That´s where it goes wrong

The problem is that for example when $reduction is 51 for example, the value $reduction_calc should be 1.51 . For some weird reason after applying the floatval() the variable $reduction_calc turns into 1.

Anybody out there who has an idea why? Thanks in advance!

Comment: `$reduction_calc = floatval(str_replace(',', '.', str_replace('.', '', $reduction_calc)));` Why are you replacing `.` with ` ` and then replacing `,` (which doesn't exist in the string if $reduction is 51 i.e) with `.` ?

Comment: This was a mistake. It should be replaced differently. Since it´s scraped content I´d like to have some sort of fallback when there appears a comma in the percentage. I should have only replaced the comma for nothing. I´ve changed that now (updated code above), but the result is the same.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$reduction_calc = floatval($reduction_calc);
```

Comment: Thanks, but I´ve already tried that and unfortunately it gives the same result.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have leading/trailing spaces in your `$reduction` or `$price` strings
Add this code before your script

```
$reduction = trim($reduction);
$price = trim($price);
```